# python pandas replace any string value in all the numeric column with constant

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

As a part of data cleaning, Dataset have 100+ column and want to check if any numeric/float columns have string values and replace all of them with constant numeric value.

Data:

| data1 | col1 | col2 | left | center |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 0.123 | 234 | 678 | -123 |
| abc | 0.1345 | 678 | 900 | -0.456 |
| def | -0.454 | **OVG** | **testing** | 8.67 |
| def | **fail** | **NVT** | **test** | 6.90 |
| def | **fail** | 890 | 900 | 532 |

Replace any string in any numeric column to -1111
output:

| data1 | col1 | col2 | left | center |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 0.123 | 234 | 678 | -123 |
| abc | 0.1345 | 678 | 900 | -0.456 |
| def | -0.454 | **-1111** | **-1111** | 8.67 |
| def | **-1111** | **-1111** | **-1111** | 6.90 |
| def | **-1111** | 890 | 900 | 532 |

Help to code in python pandas

Comment: How do you know which columns are numeric?

Answer (score 0):

use `pd.to_numeric` with `apply`

```
out = df.set_index('data1').apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')\
        .fillna(-1111).reset_index()
```

out:

```
    data1   col1        col2    left    center
0   abc     0.1230      234.0   678.0   -123.000
1   abc     0.1345      678.0   900.0   -0.456
2   def     -0.4540     -1111.0 -1111.0 8.670
3   def     -1111.0000  -1111.0 -1111.0 6.900
4   def     -1111.0000  890.0   900.0   532.000
```

**Example Code**

When asking questions about dtypes, input should be provided in code, not text.

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'data1': {0: 'abc', 1: 'abc', 2: 'def', 3: 'def', 4: 'def'}, 
         'col1': {0: '0.123', 1: '0.1345', 2: '-0.454', 3: 'fail', 4: 'fail'}, 
         'col2': {0: '234', 1: '678', 2: 'OVG', 3: 'NVT', 4: '890'}, 
         'left': {0: '678', 1: '900', 2: 'testing', 3: 'test', 4: '900'}, 
         'center': {0: -123.0, 1: -0.456, 2: 8.67, 3: 6.9, 4: 532.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```